# Tooltip with sharped edge in material using css

Tags: html, css, angular-material

Need a tooltip like this. Tried border-radius but its not working as expected. Its not getting sharped edge on left. Only curved one. Please help me on this

```
  ::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100px 0px 0px 100px !important;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: check this link `https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-beautiful-tooltips-with-only-css/`

Comment: Please share a snippet

Comment: @SunilR. https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-sidenav-example-ckkquy?file=app%2Fsidenav-autosize-example.html